# Как суммировать элементы одного массива для одинаковых элементов другого массива без циклов?

Tags: python, массивы, оптимизация, numpy

Как просуммировать элементы одного массива `[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` для одинаковых элементов в другогом массиве `[0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2]`?

То есть, для "0" это "0+30", для "1" это "10+40", для "2" это "20+50", чтобы результатом стал массив: `[30, 50, 70]`.

Но без циклов и двумерных массивов, т.к. долго.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2])
b = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
result = np.arange(3)
for n in range(3):
    ind = np.where(a == n)[0]
    result[n] = np.sum(b[ind])
result
```

Comment: Почему «без двумерных массивов»?

Comment: Есть элегантное решение для Pandas...

Comment: какое, если не тайна)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2])
b = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
print(np.bincount(a,b))
```

> [30. 50. 70.]

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
res = df.groupby("a")["b"].sum()
```

---

результат:

```
In [177]: res
Out[177]:
a
0    30
1    50
2    70
Name: b, dtype: int32

In [178]: res.to_dict()
Out[178]: {0: 30, 1: 50, 2: 70}
```

Comment: почему-то не получается массив [30, 50, 70]...
Получается:
b
0     0
10    1
20    2
30    0
40    1
50    2
Name: a, dtype: int32

Comment: Получается два столбика 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 и столбик 0,1,2,0,1,2. Name: a, dtype: int32

Comment: @bluesky, исправил ответ

Comment: супер. Спасибо!!!

Comment: отметил. Нужно поизучать Pandas. А нельзя сделать то же самое, но для array, чтобы не переводить tuple в array?

Comment: @bluesky, не понял на счёт перевода tuple -> array

Comment: Я думаю решение на чистом Numpy будет гораздо длиннее...

Comment: @MaxU не уверен, что решение на чистом numpy будет гораздо длиннее ;)

Comment: @strawdog, да, забыл про трюк с параметром weights. Но всё-таки по гибкости и возможностям трудно сравнивать np.bincount и df.groupby ;)

Comment: @MaxU тут я не спорю. Сам бы я лично тоже предпочел pandas.

Answer (score 1):

```
result=[0]*3
for i,n in zip(a,b):
    result[i] += n
```